# Flutter baseline text alignment with Wrap class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Using the `Row` class, I can make the text baseline aligned with this property:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
```

But this property seems not to be available on the `Wrap` class.
The benefit of using `Wrap` instead of `Row` is that it allows having multiline text. While the `Row` class force the content to stay into one line.

How can I keep the benefit of `Wrap`, while making the text baseline aligned?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. [There is an open issue in the Flutter Repo addressing this.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84948) While the built-in solution is not implemented yet, I did come up with a slightly-hacky workaround.

Basically, depending on your font and your needs...

Set your `Wrap()` to have `crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,`. Then you can make one of the children of your `Wrap()` a `Column()` that has a `SizedBox()` as the lowest child, with the height that you need to make it appear like your texts are using the does-not-exist `WrapCrossAlignment.baseLine`

**Example of the problem:**

[image]

**Example of the solution as outlined above (I did point out that it's kind of hacky):**
[image]

The Code:

```
class WrapBaselineHackWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
      child: Wrap(
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
        spacing: 8,
        children: [
          Text(
            '\$50,000.00',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text('Is a lot of money'),
              //this is needed because Wrap does not have WrapCrossAlignment.baseLine
              const SizedBox(height: 3),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep using Row and simply wrap Text widget with Expanded or Flexible widget.